# How to increase transform y value when an item is hovered in react-grid-layout

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

How can I increase transform Y value when an item is hovered in react-grid-layout?

When I use the developer tool to see elements style, I see `transform: translate(X, Y)`.

X and Y value is determined by react-grid-layout and I don't have a control for it.

However, I like to move an item up by 1px when it's hovered. Can I do that?

Here is [react-grid-layouyt](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout) library.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import GridLayout from "react-grid-layout";

import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const layout = [
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
    { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
    { i: "c", x: 2, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 },
    { i: "d", x: 3, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2 }
  ];

  const [lists, setLists] = useState(layout);

  const handleDragStop = (layout, oldItem, newItem) => {
    console.log("layout", layout);
    console.log("oldItem", oldItem);
    console.log("newItem", newItem);

    const sortedLayout = [...layout].sort((a, b) => {
      console.log("a.x", a.x);
      return a.x - b.x;
    });
    sortedLayout.forEach((item, index) => {
      item.x = index;
      item.y = 0;
    });

    setLists(sortedLayout);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GridLayout
        className="layout"
        layout={lists}
        cols={10}
        rowHeight={15}
        width={1200}
        margin={[10, 10]}
        onDragStop={handleDragStop}
        maxRows={1}
        compactType="horizontal"
      >
        <div key="a" className="grid-item" style={{ border: "red 3px solid" }}>
          a
        </div>
        <div
          key="b"
          className="grid-item"
          style={{ border: "green 3px solid", width: "20px" }}
        >
          b
        </div>
        <div key="c" className="grid-item" style={{ border: "blue 3px solid" }}>
          c
        </div>
        <div key="d" className="grid-item" style={{ border: "pink 3px solid" }}>
          d
        </div>
      </GridLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.layout {
  margin: 200px;
}

.grid-item {
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  width: 40px;
  background: pink;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1px);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px #3e3e3e33;
}
```

#### Attempts

I added `transform: translateY(-1px); in` .grid-item:hover`, I see box-shadow css applied correctly but not` transform`

Answer (score 1):

```
.grid-item:hover {
  top: -1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px 0px #3e3e3e33;
}
```

Having `top: -1px;` solved the problem.